# Translate regex extraction method from R to javascript

Tags: javascript, r, regex

I'm posting this question for a friend who works in javascript. In this type of string:

```
string <- '<p><strong><kE id="a2252996-46e5-4d41-a1a5-1443906a51b7">Schema: Berechnung des Funktionswerts</KE></strong></p>
  
  <p>Wenn nach den Werten einer Funktion für bestimmte x-Werte gefragt ist, sollst du die zugehörigen y-Werte berechnen.</p>
  
  <p>(Schritt 1) Setze für jedes x in der Funktion den gegebenen x-Wert ein. Berechne daraus den gesuchten y-Wert.</p>'
```

he wants to do the same in javascript that this R code does:

```
library(stringr)
str_c("[' ", str_extract(string, '(?i)(?<=<)KE id="[\\w-]+"(?=>)'), " ']")
[1] "[' kE id=\"a2252996-46e5-4d41-a1a5-1443906a51b7\" ']"
```

Any hints at how the same extraction is achieved in javascript?

Comment: You could use a capture group instead `<(KE id="[\w-]+")>` https://regex101.com/r/Ha9rNK/1 See https://jsfiddle.net/uec9dzkm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @The fourth bird pointed out, you can use the capture group `<(kE id="[\w-]+")>`  instead of the one that you listed.

```js
var string = '<p><strong><kE id="a2252996-46e5-4d41-a1a5-1443906a51b7">Schema: Berechnung des Funktionswerts</KE></strong></p>'+
             '<p>Wenn nach den Werten einer Funktion für bestimmte x-Werte gefragt ist, sollst du die zugehörigen y-Werte berechnen.</p>'+
             '<p>(Schritt 1) Setze für jedes x in der Funktion den gegebenen x-Wert ein. Berechne daraus den gesuchten y-Wert.</p>'


var extract = string.match(/<(kE id="[\w-]+")>/)[0]
                    .replace("<","[' ")
                    .replace(">"," ']")
                    .replaceAll('"', '\\"')
console.log(extract)

//Output: [' kE id=\"a2252996-46e5-4d41-a1a5-1443906a51b7\" ']
```